# Hot to map html input properties to object with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to read all page inputs ids and values
into object and pass it to function which loop throuhg them and extract id and value.

I started with:

```
function send()
{
var data = [];
var inputs = $(":text");
for (var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
   var input;
   input.id = inputs[i].attr("id");
   input.text = inputs[i].val();
   data[i] = input;
}
receive(data);
}

function receive(data)
{
    for (var input in data) {
        alert(input.id);
        alert(input.text);        
    }
}
```

Why this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding items to an array, you likely want to use `.push()` instead of accessing it via the numeric index.  Also, jQuery provides a `.each` to iterate over a set.

```
var data = [];
$(':input:not(:button)').each(function() {
   data.push({
      id: this.id,
      text: $(this).val()
   });
});
```

One more thing.  jQuery does include a `.map` function, which returns an array "mapped" over a given set which could shorten the above code down to...

```
var data = $(':input:not(:button)').map(function() {
    return { id: this.id, text: $(this).val() };
});
```

Comment: you forgot closing bracket in first example

Answer (score 3):

If you give your `input` elements a `name` attribute, you could just do this...

```
var data = $(":text").serializeArray();
```

...which results in this data structure *(taken from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/))*...

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "d",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "e",
    value: "5"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's serializeArray function

HTML:

```
<form id="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="a1" value="test" />
    <input type="text" name="a2" value="test2" />
    <input type="text" name="a3" value="test2" />
    <input type="text" name="a4" value="test2" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function getData(){
    var data = $("#test").serializeArray();
    for(var i in data){
       alert(data[i].name+":"+data[i].value);   
    }
}
```

jsFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/k2Dd4/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the exact implementation in jQuery, but in Javascript I would do it as

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var textelems;

for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type == "text") {
        tempElem = [];
        tempElem['id'] = inputs[i].id;
        tempElem['value'] = inputs[i].value;
        textelems.push(tempElem);
    }
}
```

This would give you a 2D-array (tempElems) where each index is a textbox with its own indexes of id and value.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code would look like:

```
function send()
{
var data = [];
var inputs = $(":text");
for (var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
    var input = {};
    input.id = $("#" + inputs[i].id).attr("id");
    input.text = $("#" + inputs[i].id).val();            
    data[i] = input;
}
receive(data);
}

function receive(data)
{
    for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
       alert(data[i].id);
       alert(data[i].text);
    }
}
```